# ASP.NET Membership Provider - Specify settings in database rather than Web.config

Tags: asp.net, security, membership

I'm using the ASP.NET membership provider for authentication of users in my web app.

I want to do two things

1. To enable the client to configure settings such as maxInvalidPasswordAttempts and passwordAttemptWindow without having to know about the web.config (e.g. through a UI)
2. To have the ability to share these settings across several applications so can define them once in a SQL database then all web apps on the server can use the same settings.

I'm not sure if either of these are possible though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you implementing you're own Custom Membership Provider ?

The properties of the default membership provider are wired through to the web.config values, but if you implement your own version, it should be relatively trivial to override the defaults and pull those values from a DB instead...

HAve a look at the [example implementation on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6tc47t75(VS.80).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You could use such property of Membership provider [MaxInvalidPasswordAttempts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membership.maxinvalidpasswordattempts.aspx) and write your implementation of populating settings from database.